# React Props updating on set state hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The props to the child component is updating on `handleOnChange` event. Below is sample code structure.

```js
const { useCallback, useEffect, useState } = React;
//think this is coming from parent obj
const retrieveData = () =>
  Promise.resolve({
    English: { v1: "10", v2: "11", v3: "34" },
    Hindi: { v1: "14", v2: "16", v3: "18" },
  });

const createKey = (...values) => values.join("-");
const splitKey = (key) => key.split("-");

const App = ({ retrieveData }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(retrieveData.English);

  //this retrieveData.English always updating on handleChange
  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveData().then(setData);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = useCallback(({ target }) => {
    const [lang, key] = splitKey(target.name);
    setData((oldData) => {
      const newData = { ...oldData };
      newData[lang][key] = target.value;
      return newData;
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <form>
      {Object.entries(data).map(([lang, item]) => (
        <div key={lang} className="row">
          <div className="head">{lang}</div>
          <ul>
            {Object.entries(item).map(([key, val]) => (
              <li key={createKey(lang, key)}>
                <label>{key}</label>
                <input
                  name={createKey(lang, key)}
                  value={val}
                  onInput={handleChange}
                />
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

In the above case, the props obj value also updating on the `handleChange` `setData`. I am not sure what I am missing. I need to compare the initial obj values with handle change values. Any idea on this.

Comment: You have not posted enough code.  Additionally there's no return for that component so that code shouldn't be working in any scenario.

Comment: Updated the code. Any idea? the issue is I am not able to compare the props(initial props obj) with changed(handle on change) values.

Answer (score 0):

in this way, the state will be updated with the data entered in the input.

```
const [initVal, setInitVal] = useState(obj.values)
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInitVal(e)
  })
  <input value={initVal} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)} />
}
```

Comment: obj.values also will change on the time of setInitVal? In my case obj.values also changing. I have updated the code example. Can you check once.